# PHP fputcsv: adding document properties

Tags: php, csv, export-to-csv, xls, fputcsv

I've been searching around for a while about the possibility of adding document properties to a .csv file (such as the Author, the Program name and so on) like those you can add to an .xls file but I ended up founding NO documentation about this.

Is this an Excel/Office related feature or can I achieve it even on .csv files?

Comment: No, you can't do this. CSV files are purely raw row/column data, nothing more.... if you need document properties for spreadsheet data, then you need a true spreadsheet format like xls BIFF or xlsx OfficeOpenXML or ods OASIS